# How to open NewWindow over Main Window in UWP and disable the background Window(MainWindow) Interaction?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to open `NewWindow` over Main Window in UWP and disable the background Window(MainWindow) Interaction.

What I Have Tried?

```
AppWindow appWindow = await AppWindow.TryCreateAsync();
Frame appWindowContentFrame = new Frame();
appWindowContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(AppWindowPage));
AppWindowPage page = (AppWindowPage)appWindowContentFrame.Content;
page.MyAppWindow = appWindow;
page.TextColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(colorPicker.Color);
ElementCompositionPreview.SetAppWindowContent(appWindow, appWindowContentFrame);
appWindow.Title = "App Window " + AppWindows.Count.ToString();
await appWindow.TryShowAsync();
```

It Opens the new Window, but I want to disable the background interaction and the new Window must be closed only when a button is clicked which is present in `NewWindow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, currently UWP does not have any API to limit the interaction of the entire window.

A more likely solution is to create a `Grid` with `high transparency` in the Main Window, covering all controls, thereby blocking click interaction:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <!-- Main content -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="MaskGrid" Background="White" Opacity="0.01" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Grid>
```

Before calling `await appWindow.TryShowAsync()` you can set `MaskGrid.Visibility = "Visible"`. But this cannot restrict the keyboard to use the Tab key to switch controls.